# Change jCarousel direction

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousel

I have a jCarousel implemented with the auto slide mode activated. I want to invert the direction  of the movement when I arrive to a concrete slide number. 
In other words, the carousel is going to the right and I want it to go back (to the left) when the index of the slide is 5.
I can get the index of the slide and launch a function when it's five, but I don't know how to make it go back.

Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
//From Left to Right

$('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
    target: '-=1'
});


//From right to Left

$('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
    target: '+=1'
});
```

`=1`  indicates position of slide and `-/+` sign indicates direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the option `scroll: -1`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to add `wrap: 'last',` to your initialization?
[see here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html)

Answer (score 1):

[After doing these guidelines](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html#rtl)

Change `li` direction to `right`:

```
.jcarousel li {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `rtl: true` in the options.

(rtl stands for Right-to-Left, and defaults to false)

Comment: But it's possible to change the options of a carousel that is currently running? I can enter code inside the callback function that I run when slide index it's five, but I don't know how to change the current carousel options when it's executing.